# Using Service Bus 1.0 with Saml

Tags: c#, wcf, claims-based-identity, servicebus

I'm currently building a cross domain messaging service that uses claims to communicate with services inside the domain.  In my messaging service I have:

```
        this.messageFactory = MessagingFactory.Create();
        this.namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.Create();

        TokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSamlTokenProvider(saml, 
            new Uri("https://<Messaging service>:9355/<Application Namespace>/"));

        this.messageFactory.GetSettings().TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.namespaceManager.Settings.TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
```

where the saml variable is a string of xml representing my saml token.
Later on I call

```
        if (this.namespaceManager.TopicExists(topicName) == false)
        {
            this.namespaceManager.CreateTopic(topicName);
        }
```

When the if statement is called I get this error:

`The token provider service was not avaliable when obtaining a token for 'https://<Messaging service>:9355/<Application Namespace>/WRAPv0.9/'.`

With an inner exception of:

`The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

But when I browse to address I get a response in the web page:

`<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title><subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle><id>uuid:7ad43729-3ed5-4c35-9987-48a34036d267;id=4</id><updated>2013-09-24T17:50:26Z</updated><generator>Service Bus 1.0</generator></feed>`

Any ideas if this is a config issue or am I missing something that's needed for my token?